# jQuery selector except $ and jquery

Tags: jquery

1. Can we use different name as a selector in jQuery **except $ and jQuery**?
2. If we are using two different frameworks which uses the same shortcut, one of them might stop working. At this moment we use **noConflict()** method. So is it a good practice to use it in only one framework (with jQuery) to solve above question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)

Comment: 1) yes 2) it's "good practice" to only use one framework.  Not always an option I guess, but some don't work well together (not just due to reusing `$`)

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is assign jQuery to a different variable:

```js
var foo = jQuery.noConflict();

foo(".myclass#mydiv").toggle();
```

Reference: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

If you are using 2 different jQuery versions on the same page,

```js
var new$ = jQuery.noConflict(true);

// Usage
new$(".foo#bar[type=baz]").hide();

// Version Matching
console.log($.fn.jquery) // Other version
console.log(new$.fn.jquery) // Version defined above
```